# Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed. Error with ar_track_alvar package while building ros workspace

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I am a newbie in ROS and Gazebo. I am trying to build the ROS workspace by running the setup_melodic.bash file as per [this](https://github.com/erlerobot/gym-gazebo/blob/master/INSTALL.md#ubuntu-1804) installation guide but getting [these](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/issues/71) errors. I have
**ROS Melodic: Desktop-Full version** and **Gazebo 9.0.0** installed in my laptop. I already installed all ROS Melodic related dependencies and opencv using below command

`sudo apt -y install python3-opencv`.

Specifications:

- os - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- python version - 3.6.8
- opencv version - 4.0.1-openvino

Could someone please help me figuring out the cause of these errors?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, ROS does not have official support for Python 3. Also, ROS ships with a particular version of OpenCV and might cause conflicts with other versions. So I would recommend sticking to the default verions of Python and OpenCV.  If you need to use different version, I would suggest using Anaconda environments or virtual environments to keep them separate from the main system.

Comment: I think you are right. I installed all ROS dependencies for python3, but I firmly believe there is some problem with my opencv version as you can see its intel openvino. It's just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use ROS Fuerte for Ubuntu 10.04 instead of Melodic as Fuerte was built with huge support for 10.04, that might remove the errors you are experiencing.